# Compress UI for iPhone 4/4s from iPhone 5+

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Is there a way to easily condense our current app to fit on 3.5"? We designed it for 4" but for our purposes we would like to do something to make it work easily for smaller devices. Something along the lines of how iPhone apps get scaled up for iPads, but in reverse? It doesn't have to be approved solution for app store, since this is for internal use.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing automatic that can be done. You need to update your UI using auto-layout.